# Selecting columns based on certain conditions in a data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

I have a `data.table` in `R` with 200 columns with integer values.

One of the columns is named group and it has 100 different possible values.

So, when I subset using: `subDT<-DT[group==N]`, for instance, and if I do,  `sum(subDT$columnX)`, maybe the value of the sum will be 0.

So what I want to do is to display `subDT`, but only the columns where `sum(subDT$columnN)!=0`, something like `subDT[group==0,.(columns where sum(column)>0)]`, keeping the names of the columns intact of course.

---

**EDIT**

An example using the mtcars data would be:

```
DT<-as.data.table(mtcars)
```

Let's say that we want to subset mtcars and get the rows where carb is 1, but display the columns only if the sum of the subset is less than 10:

```
DT[carb == 1, (sapply(DT[carb == 1],sum) < 10), with = FALSE]
```

In this case, the columns that will be displayed are only vs,am and carb because the sum of those columns is less than 10

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your data. Is it really a `data.table` or a `data.frame`?

Comment: @Molx the syntax is clearly a `data.table` one

Comment: You should really provide a reproducible example, because as it stands now, this questions isn't useful to no one and should be closed IMO

Comment: I really made my best effort to be as clear as possible including data.table in the title and tag and being as explicit as possible... Thanks anyway the solution is down there

Comment: Did you follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) link or not?

Comment: I did... I added the reproducible example so maybe it can be more useful to people.

Comment: @akrun probably `lapply(.SD, sum) < 10` will be more efficient.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the sum is taken after the filter:

`DT[group == N, !(sapply(DT[group == N],sum) == 0), with = FALSE]`

Can be made faster with setkey:

```
setkey(DT,group)
DT[N, !(sapply(DT[N],sum) == 0), with = FALSE]
```